# StringBuilder Append replacing data- issue

Tags: excel, string, vb.net, append, stringbuilder

From a very large Excel file, We loop and store the values from 3 of the columns into variables( uName(Row), mgrName(Row), title(Row) ).  From this excel, we also get the number of rows.

The issue comes when I am trying to use StringBuilder to create a separate .xls file to be used later in the application.  The code I have looks like this:

```
    Dim XLstring As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim newfile As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim fileTitle

    XLstring.Append("Name,Manager,Title" & vbCrLf)

    For X As Integer = 2 To countrows
        If X = countrows Then
            MsgBox(countrows)
            MsgBox(uName(X) & "," & mgrName(X) & "," & title(X))
        End If

        XLstring.Append(uName(X) & "," & mgrName(X) & "," & title(X) & vbCrLf)
    Next

    fileTitle = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".xls"
    filePath2 = "myPath" & fileTitle

    newfile = File.CreateText(filePath2)
    newfile.WriteLine(XLstring)
```

This works for the most part.  I can see that I am grabbing the correct number of rows as well as the correct information in the last row using MsgBox.  When I open the resulting .xls file however, there are entries missing at the end of the file.  In addition, if I were to change

```
XLstring.Append("Name,Manager,Title" & vbCrLf)
```

to something like

```
XLstring.Append("Name,Manager" & vbCrLf)
```

the exact number of characters I removed from the Append line will now successfully appear at the end of the file where the information is missing.

Is there some weird functionality that I am not understanding using these functions?  I am completey lost and don't understand this behavior.

Comment: I retagged this to VB.Net as its not VBA

Comment: Are you closing newFile to flush it?  `.WriteAllText` is simpler: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @AlexK. So I added the line   "newfile.Flush()" which seems to have worked. Do you think simply adding that will cause any other issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file when you're done:

```
newfile.Close()
```

On a side note, your file is being saved with the XLS extension, but since you are exporting a list of comma-separated values, I would suggest saving in CSV format instead.

Comment: Thank you. This works as well as newfile.Flush(), though I am not sure which one directly fixes the issue I was having.  The reason I am saving it as a .xls is because this file is used to create a visio file, so it needs to be in this format

Comment: Glad I could help.  The difference is that `.Flush()` will flush the buffer (write changes to disk) but leave the file open so you can continue to append lines to it, whereas `.Close()` will also close the file, meaning it will need to be reopened if you want to append more lines.  Regardless of how often you flush, you should always close the file when you're finished.

Comment: Your StreamWriter needs to be disposed. Any object that has a `Dispose` method needs to be disposed as it probably has unmanaged resources that need to be tidied up. This can be accomplished either by using a Using block or calling dispose directly.